# Is it possible to add 'gravity' to a NumPy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I need to create a [Connect Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four)-type game using Python. I chose to approach this using a NumPy array constructed of zeros.

Moves are made using input() and then translated to the corresponding matrix position. I need to add a function to check if the value beneath the placement location is equal to 0 or not and if it is equal to 0 the location needs to move down and repeat the process.

I tried

```
if row_gravity[player_row_move + 1] != 0:
    game_board[player_row_move, player_move] = 1
    print(game_board)
    player_state = 1
else:
    player_row_move = player_row_move + 1
```

with row_gravity being defined as `row_gravity = game_board.T[player_row_move]` where *game_board* is the array with dimension x,y.

I am not sure what I was expecting with this solution (apart from hoping it would work).

Comment: i see that i made some mistakes with the code block, my apologies for that to anyone who might be able to help

Comment: I woudl add more information in the question, like all the variables that you didn't define

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an Idea:

```py
import numpy as np


def gravity(m: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    for (y, x), e in np.ndenumerate(m[:-1, :]):
        if m[y + 1, x] == 0:
            m[y, x] = 0
            m[y + 1, x] = e
    return m


a = np.array([
        [2, 0, 5],
        [0, 6, 0],
        [3, 2, 0],
    ])
print(gravity(a))
```

The function iterates over all but the last row and moves each element down if there is space underneath. As the upper rows are checked first points will "trippel" down.

There is one potential problem though. The code will fail if more than one element is "floating", for example with this array:

```py
a = np.array([
        [2, 0, 5],
        [0, 6, 4],
        [3, 2, 0],
    ])
```

But if I understand your Plan correctly this shouldn't affect you as you will only ever add a single new element.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, i'm relatively new to using larger matrixes (only really worked with 1xA arrays before)